# Google Data Studio apparently bugging year sorting in combined data sources

Tags: looker-studio

I have a combined data source that seems to work fine when I sort a bar chart using any metric.

[image]

However, as you can notice, the years are not in correct order.
When I select sorting ("Classificar") as year ("Ano") it bugs.

[image]

I noticed it is classifying "Ano" in the sorting area as a metric, but as a matter of facts thats a dimension. I didn't manage to find a way to change that.

About the data:
`Ano` is years in XXXX format
`Receita Líquida` is Net Revenues in number format

Am I doing something wrong or that's a data studio bug and there is nothing we can do?
Unfortunately, not using combined data sources is not an option in this case (but when I cancel the combined data sources, it works fine and sorts by the year as it should be - still as a metric but it works).

Answer (score 1):

Well, no one answered and I finally found a way to solve it.
Google Data Studio is indeed bugging the year sorting. However it only happens if year is a date object or a number. I fixed it when I turned it into text.